How does EMF strength decrease with distance from a power transformer?
I'm trying to understand how electromagnetic fields (EMF) decrease with distance from a power transformation station. If the EMF at the station's outer wall is around 150 µT, how far would I need to be for the field to drop below 0.25 µT?
In case it is relevant, assume the station converts 30,000V to 400V, and the EMF source is about 3 meters from the outer wall (inside the station). How should I account for the type of EMF source (e.g., point or line source) and the presence of a brick wall? I'm unclear on how much the wall would block or absorb EMF and how to factor that into the calculation.

For what purpose, are you receiving interference from a nearby substation?

The earth's magnetic field is around 60 micro-teslas so, getting down to below that isn't going to happen.

A reference may be "Human Interaction with Electromagnetic Fields: Computational Models in Dosimetry" by Dragan Poljak & Mario Cvetković. In particular, see section 3.1.2 Fields Generated by Substation Transformers (and the related subsection 3.1.2.2 The Magnetic Field.)

It depends which direction you go. To reach 0.25 μT you'd have to go either into deep space or somewhere with some kind of active equipment to cancel out the earth's magnetic field (this does exist, for scientific purposes).

@timwilliams I am concerned about the health effects a substation could have when living in close proximity. The WHO warms about risks for kids at or above 0.3 micro tesla

@Hearth I do understand that there is always some background radiation. My question is about the radiation from the transformer station specifically. It is neither about total exposure nor sources unrelated to the station.

@periblepsis Thank you for the recommendation. May I ask you for further guidance, or if possible a simplified explanation, in form of an answer? I am not trained in the field, so it is quite hard for me to navigate and ingest information. I tried to do my own research before asking, but the best approximation I could reach was $ B(r) = B_0 / r^2 $ which gives $r = r_0 * /sqrt{B_0 / B(r)} $

@S.G. Got it. Yes, I'll admit that the textbook reads about like this YouTube on the Bloch Theorem and the Central Equation plays. But that textbook is directed in part at answering health questions. To cut to the short of 3.1.2, the field drops off $\propto\frac1{r^{,3}}$.

It generally falls off as the cube of the distance divided by the dimensions of the EMF-generating structure. This is the general rule for a dipole.
So, if the transformer's dimension is about 3 m (not the same as the transformer to wall distance), then for an attenuation of 0.25/150 = 1/600, or 1/8^3, you'd need to be 8*3 = 24 m away.
This a very general approximation and won't apply if there are multiple transformers, or other metal shields (wire fence) -- generally these will further attenuate the signal.
For the comments about Earth's magnetic field -- that's a DC field, the OP is concerned about AC fields.
Note that the Q is about magnetic fields, while the acronym EMF is used (this is for electric fields). However the same 1/R^3 calculation would occur.
